# ranking SQL in MySQL for vendors and services

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to filter vendors who provide specific set of services.

There is many to many relationship between vendor and services.

A vendor can provide any number of services. Consider below table.

I need to filter out vendors who're providing specified services for example: 
Services: 301,302,303,304

Since in this case no single vendor provides all of these services, I can choose maximum of two vendors for fulfilling services to customer

```
Vendor  Services
1001    301
1001    303
1002    302
1002    303
1002    304
1003    302
1003    303
1004    304
```

This is just a very basic example, in real scenario there can multiple vendors who provides same services. I can choose any 2 ve`enter code here`ndors who together provides all services.

Would be thankful if you provide SQL query in MySQL.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can use `group by` and `having`:

```
select vendor
from belowtable
where service in (301, 302, 303, 304)
group by vendor
having count(*) = 4;
```

If duplicates are permitted in `belowtable`, then use `count(distinct service)` in the `having` clause.

Comment: (assuming - quite reasonably - that a PRIMARY KEY is formed on [vendor,services])

Comment: @Gordon Linoff This will group by vendors and vendors doesn't provide all services so grouping will give results where 4 count will not be there. It'll be less than 4 like 3,2 or 1

Comment: In this case I need any 2 vendors who can together provide these 4 services.

Comment: @user1221049 . . . In my opinion, the question you asked is about one vendor, not pairs of vendors, and this question answers it.  You should ask *another* question about pairs of vendors.